# View on_failure_callback DAG logger

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's take an example DAG.

[image: DAG Graph]

Here is the code for it.

```py
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


def task_failure_notification_alert(context):
    logging.info("Task context details: %s", str(context))


def dag_failure_notification_alert(context):
    logging.info("DAG context details: %s", str(context))


def red_exception_task(ti: TaskInstance, **kwargs):
    raise Exception('red')


default_args = {
    "owner": "analytics",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 12, 12),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(),
    "schedule_interval": "@daily"
}

dag = DAG('logger_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False,
          on_failure_callback=dag_failure_notification_alert
          )

start_task = DummyOperator(task_id="start_task", dag=dag, on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert)
red_task = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='red_task',
    python_callable=red_exception_task,
    provide_context=True,
    on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert
)
end_task = DummyOperator(task_id="end_task", dag=dag, on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert)

start_task >> red_task >> end_task
```

We can see two functions i.e. `task_failure_notification_alert` and `dag_failure_notification_alert` are being called in case of failures.
We can see logs in case of Task failure by the below steps.

We can see logs for the task as below.

[image: Task options screen]

[image: Logs screen]

but I am unable to find logs for the `on_failure_callback` of DAG anywhere in UI. Where can we see it?

Comment: Seems the airflow UI doesn't show this kind of logs? I've run your code on a standalone instance from command line and from UI as well and the log line showing execution of the dag call back was there: ~/airflow/logs/scheduler/[current_date]/dag_name.py
However I was not able to find it through UI...

Answer (score 3):

Under airflow/logs find the "scheduler" folder, under it look for the specific date you ran the Dag for example 2022-12-03 and there you will see name of the dag_file.log.